# How to pass image url array ["url1","url2"] to InitialState props in React Upload Gallery

Tags: reactjs, image

I'm trying develop feature of adding/removing images in my system using [React Upload Gallery](https://github.com/TPMinan/react-upload-gallery). But I was unable to render the component with initial state. I'm looking help for this.

I have a predefined images in form of array. the state look like this:

`images = ["imageURI1","imageURI2"]`

The url is returning images and its working. So I wanted to assign this array into the component `initialstate` props so that the component will render with these images on first load but could find way to do it.

I've tried 
`initialState={[{source: this.state.images[0], name: 'image1'}]}`
But seem not to be working.I received the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCreated' of undefined`

Here is the code snippet

```
<RUG
  customRequest={handleImageUpload}
  source={response => response}
  onChange={handleImageChange}
  initialState={[{source: this.state.images[0], name: 'image1'}]}
/>
```

Comment: how is it not working, are you get any error ?

Comment: Post the component where you are passing `initialState` props, also post calling of the same.

Comment: yes, I received error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCreated' of undefined`

Comment: Change this `source={response => response}` to `source={response => response.source}`

Comment: I got the same error, I'm using server side rendering will this be an issue?